# Rails 3.2 SSRS and SavonRD

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, reporting-services, pdf-generation, rendering

I'm integrating my Rails 3.2 app with SSRS for reporting using Savonrb to do the Soap call to the SSRS web service. Everything is finally working and I can successfully make the following calls:

1. LoadReport
2. SetExecutionParameters
3. Render

The render call takes a format parameter (in my case PDF) and returns an XML response. I thought the call would result in the report being rendered in a pdf, but it doesn't. What do I need to do with the response object to render the report?

code below:

```
response = @client.call(:load_report, message: {report: "/path/to/report"} )

response =  @client.call(:set_execution_parameters, message: { "Parameters" => param1} )

response =  @client.call(:render, message: {"Format" => "PDF"})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I need to take the xml string that was returned from the render call and decode it to Base64, write it to a file, and then user send_file to stream the file to the browser. This works now, code below:

```
response =  @newClient.call(:render, message: {"Format" => "PDF"})
@results = response.to_hash

@report = @results[:render_response][:result]
@extension = @results[:render_response][:extension]
@mime_type = @results[:render_response][:mime_type]
@report_name = "MyReportName.pdf" # this should be dynamically generated from a param passed in the call to run_report 

File.open(@report_name, "wb+") do |f|
  f.puts Base64.decode64(@report)
end



@file = File.open(@report_name, 'r')

   send_file @file, :filename => @report_name, :type => "application/pdf; charset=utf-8", :disposition => "attachment"
```